# play framework returns 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: java, reactjs, playframework

Hi my play framework application returns

```
415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Post:

```
 fetch(API_URL+'/process', {
        method: "POST",
        header: {"contentType": "application/json;charset=utf-8"},
        body: JSON.stringify(newProcess)
    });
```

controller code for the post thod looks like:

```
 @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
 public Result createProcess(){

    System.out.println("TEST");
    System.out.println(request().body());
```

whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are setting the incorrect header**s**, try this:

```js
fetch(API_URL + '/process', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(newProcess)
});
```